# Getting iframe page name/value pairs in parent page submit in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

I have a Parent Page that includes an iframe containing html page with many field. The parent page contains the "Save" button. Now i want to get the values of iframe page while submitting the parent page. How can i access the iframe pages fields in parent page submit?

Answer (score 0):

I know that you didn't tag this as jQuery, but if you wanted to use jQuery the way you could grab the contents of the iframe would be:

```
$('#yourIframe').contents()
```

More info can be found [here](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).